# Changing firefox's prefs.js from browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, printing, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Before firefox's ver 57 I was using https://github.com/edabg/jsprintsetup to change the printing configuration on the fly. This is no longer possible.

Using `about:config` on the browser window I can change the settings I want and when opening a new tab the changes are reflected.

My question is how do I do this after version 57? Im open to developing an extension or an add-on for firefox for this. Some of the preferences I want to change is the `print.{printer}.print_orientation`,`print.always_print_silent` etc

This is used only within the companys Intranet system, so security wont be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no WebExtension API for preferences manipulation.

The only way out is to implement your own experiment API, but extensions with experiment API work only on Firefox Nightly and Developer Edition.